# Numeric simulation of light propagation throug micropores in water

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, simulations, diffraction, software

I am interested in the simulation of the propagation of light through the surface of the silicon diatom frustule. Could you recommend me any free program that allow to perform such simulation? That is, the program should allow to simulate the propagation of light through the perforated silicon plate. The size of perforations is less than a micron and the plate is not necessarily flat.

Comment: When you say "free program that allow to perform such simulation", how much work are you willing to do?  You have to set up the simulation but are you expecting a free s/w with optics and materials in it, or just a free high level programming s/w.  Like octave or scilab?

Comment: I mean a program that has no cost like octave and scilab, you've mentioned.

Comment: Okay but how much work are you willing to do to program the sim?

Comment: I can construct (program) a geometric surface wtih the necessary texture and I want to use a completed module for simulating diffractive optic. So I don't want to program optic laws.

Comment: Sounds like you need an open source version of zmax.  Google that phrase and see what you get

Comment: When I googling, I found only Zemax software which is not open source. Could you provide a link, please?

Comment: No I can't.   That's why I recommend Google.  I write my own sw in c++, and have used octave and scilab.   I know zmax and its very expensive.   When I'm looking for open source code for anything the first thing I try is Google "open source version of <name of sw>.  You could try open source optics simulator,  or open source electromagnetic wave sim.  I'm trying to help you get some traction.